# How do I know the columnizing is done?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using css property `-column-width` (and of course `-moz-column-width` and `-webkit-column-width`) to columnize the content on a webpage. The problem is when there are too much content, the proccess of columnizing is kind of slow, and can take seconds. I was told to put a spinner to alert user that the page is not ready yet, and the spinner also should block UI. But I can't find appropriate event to disable spinner. The `$(document).ready()` is too early. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried $(document).load() ?

Comment: Can you do an [MCVE](/help/mcve)? It's hard to help without more information.

Comment: Yes, Diogo, I tried, thank you for your contribution. Unfortunately, it is not working, the event never rises.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `$(document).ready()` is too early, you could use `$(window).load(...)`. That's **really** late in the process, but I can't think of anything interim.

If there's anything you can check the placement of, you could start polling as of `$(document).ready()` and wait for the placement to match what you expect or stop changing or some such. Polling every 10ms or so won't have any appreciable impact, and may let you get rid of the spinner earlier than the `load` event.

Comment: Yes! You're the best! `$(window).load(...)` works just as I wanted!